# Repopulate a static select input

Tags: form, validation

I have a form that contains a static select input of U.S. States:

```
<select id="state" name="state" class="form-control">
<option value=""> Select </option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
....
</select>
```

I have the validation figured out on my form, and also have my text inputs getting repopulated if there are any validation errors. I am curious about the best method to repopulate my select input.

I can access the value that was entered via:

```
{% set state = craft.request.getParam('state') %}
```

Which will give me "AL" or "AK" (whichever was chosen). This is fine, but because my list is static, do I now need to have logic on every option?

For example, something like this...

```
<option value="AL" {% if state == AL %}selected="selected" {%endif%}>Alabama</option>
```

Or, is there a better way all together?

FWIW, here is how I am repopulating my text inputs:

```
value="{% if model is defined %}{{ model.name }}{% endif %}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think there's a better way, you need to add that conditional to each select option.
But what you could do is to refactor a bit and move that logic to a [Twig macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html).

```
{% macro stateOption(id, name, selectedId) %}
    <option value="{{ id }}"{{ id == selectedId ? ' selected="selected"' }}>{{ name }}</option>
{% endmacro %}
{% import _self as forms %}

{% set selectedId = craft.request.getParam('state') %}

{% set states = {
    'AL': 'Alabama',
    'AK': 'Alaska',
    'AZ': 'Arizona',
} %}

<select id="state" name="state">
    <option value="">Select</option>

    {# Go through states and use the custom macro to generate the select options #}
    {% for id, name in states %}
        {{ forms.stateOption(id, name, selectedId) }}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Ah - this is exactly the shove I needed. (Obviously) I'm new to twig development, and was searching the docs for all the wrong things it seems. I figured I would have to do it 50x times, (yuck) but the macro is the way to roll.  Thank you very much!!